# There is a "lag" or "delay" when it comes to changing many ImageIcons inside JLabels. How to avoid?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, lag, imageicon

I am currently working on a 2D-simulator game that takes place in a Perlin noise-generated terrain that is shown on a 41x23 grid. The player (as of the moment, at the center but not yet given an overlaying icon) can move using the arrow keys, but doing so will keep the player static but move the map accordingly. However, when I move, the JFrame lags like hell. Some JLabel instances change their ImageIcons slower than others, creating huge latency and un-"playability". I have tried replacing the inefficient function update with four functions that "efficiently" move the player faster - but the lag or delay remains. I have also reformatted and refactored the function, to no avail. So, I am stuck.

For more info, I am using 32x32 icons that represent the structures and the domain, and the JFrame is 1280x720 in size. I am confident that this is not due to hardware, as the program runs with other memory- or core- consuming programs. Is there any way to solve the lag or delay?

[image]

**Main Class**

```java
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.RescaleOp;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Main {

    private JFrame frame;
    public static ImageIcon water = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/textures/terrain/water.png")).getImage().getScaledInstance(32, 32, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
    public static ImageIcon sand = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/textures/terrain/sand.png")).getImage().getScaledInstance(32, 32, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
    public static ImageIcon grass = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/textures/terrain/grass.png")).getImage().getScaledInstance(32, 32, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
    public static ImageIcon stone = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/textures/terrain/stone.png")).getImage().getScaledInstance(32, 32, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
    public static ImageIcon ice = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/textures/terrain/ice.png")).getImage().getScaledInstance(32, 32, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
    public static ImageIcon oak = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/textures/structure/oak.png")).getImage().getScaledInstance(32, 32, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
    public static ImageIcon nullstructure = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/textures/structure/nullstructure.png")).getImage().getScaledInstance(32, 32,  Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Main window = new Main();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    public Main() throws InterruptedException {
        initialize();
        
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    private void initialize() throws InterruptedException {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setBounds(0, 0, 1280, 720);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        Coordinate playerPos = new Coordinate(0,0);
        JLabel[][] terrainArray = new JLabel[41][23];
        JLabel[][] structureArray = new JLabel[41][23];
        JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        layeredPane.setBounds(0, 0, 1280, 720);
        frame.getContentPane().add(layeredPane);
        layeredPane.setLayout(null);
            JPanel terrainGrid = new JPanel();
            terrainGrid.setBounds(0, 0, 1280, 720);
            layeredPane.add(terrainGrid);
            GridBagLayout gbl_terrainGrid = new GridBagLayout();
            gbl_terrainGrid.columnWidths = new int[]{0};
            gbl_terrainGrid.rowHeights = new int[]{0};
            gbl_terrainGrid.columnWeights = new double[]{Double.MIN_VALUE};
            gbl_terrainGrid.rowWeights = new double[]{Double.MIN_VALUE};
            terrainGrid.setLayout(gbl_terrainGrid);
            
            JPanel structureGrid = new JPanel();
            layeredPane.setLayer(structureGrid, Integer.valueOf(1));
            structureGrid.setBounds(0, 0, 1280, 720);
            structureGrid.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
            structureGrid.setOpaque(false);
            layeredPane.add(structureGrid);
            GridBagLayout gbl_structureGrid = new GridBagLayout();
            gbl_structureGrid.columnWidths = new int[]{0};
            gbl_structureGrid.rowHeights = new int[]{0};
            gbl_structureGrid.columnWeights = new double[]{Double.MIN_VALUE};
            gbl_structureGrid.rowWeights = new double[]{Double.MIN_VALUE};
            structureGrid.setLayout(gbl_structureGrid); 
        
            Coordinate[][] map = new Coordinate[Coordinate.MAP_SIZE][Coordinate.MAP_SIZE];
            for(int i = 0; i < Coordinate.MAP_SIZE; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < Coordinate.MAP_SIZE; j++) {
                    map[i][j] = new Coordinate(i - ((Coordinate.MAP_SIZE - 1)/2) , j - ((Coordinate.MAP_SIZE - 1)/2));
                }
            }
            
            for(int i = 0; i < 41; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < 23; j++) {
                    terrainArray[i][j] = new JLabel("");
                    structureArray[i][j] = new JLabel("");
                    structureArray[i][j].setIcon(Main.nullstructure);
                    terrainArray[i][j].setIcon(findEntry(map, new Coordinate(playerPos.getX() - 20 + i, playerPos.getZ() - 11 + j)).returnTerrainIcon());
                    structureArray[i][j].setIcon(findEntry(map, new Coordinate(playerPos.getX() - 20 + i, playerPos.getZ() - 11 + j)).returnStructureIcon());
                    
                    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                        gbc.gridx = i; gbc.gridy = j;
                        terrainGrid.add(terrainArray[i][j], gbc);
                        structureGrid.add(structureArray[i][j],gbc);
                }
            }
        
        frame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                    playerPos.setZ(playerPos.getZ() - 1);
                    moveUP(terrainArray, structureArray, map, playerPos);
                    
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                    playerPos.setZ(playerPos.getZ() + 1);
                    moveDOWN(terrainArray, structureArray, map, playerPos);
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                    playerPos.setX(playerPos.getX() + 1);
                    moveRIGHT(terrainArray, structureArray, map, playerPos);
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                    playerPos.setX(playerPos.getX() - 1);
                    moveLEFT(terrainArray, structureArray, map, playerPos);
                    break;
                }
                
            }
        });
    }
    
    public void moveUP(JLabel[][] terrainArray, JLabel[][] structureArray, Coordinate[][] map, Coordinate playerPos) {
        for(int x = 0; x < 41; x++) {
            for(int z = 22; z > 0; z--) {       //23 - 1
                terrainArray[x][z].setIcon(terrainArray[x][z-1].getIcon());
                structureArray[x][z].setIcon(structureArray[x][z-1].getIcon());
            }
            terrainArray[x][0].setIcon(findEntry(map, new Coordinate(playerPos.getX() - 20 + x, playerPos.getZ() - 11)).returnTerrainIcon()); 
            structureArray[x][0].setIcon(findEntry(map, new Coordinate(playerPos.getX() - 20 + x, playerPos.getZ() - 11)).returnStructureIcon());
        }
    }
    
    public void moveDOWN(JLabel[][] terrainArray, JLabel[][] structureArray, Coordinate[][] map, Coordinate playerPos) {
        for(int x = 0; x < 41; x++) {
            for(int z = 0; z < 22; z++) {       //23 - 1
                terrainArray[x][z].setIcon(terrainArray[x][z+1].getIcon());
                structureArray[x][z].setIcon(structureArray[x][z+1].getIcon());
            }
            terrainArray[x][22].setIcon(findEntry(map, new Coordinate(playerPos.getX() - 20 + x, playerPos.getZ() + 11)).returnTerrainIcon()); 
            structureArray[x][22].setIcon(findEntry(map, new Coordinate(playerPos.getX() - 20 + x, playerPos.getZ() + 11)).returnStructureIcon());
        }
    }
    
    public void moveLEFT(JLabel[][] terrainArray, JLabel[][] structureArray, Coordinate[][] map, Coordinate playerPos) {
        for(int z = 0; z < 23; z++) {
            for(int x = 40; x > 0; x--) {
                terrainArray[x][z].setIcon(terrainArray[x-1][z].getIcon());
                structureArray[x][z].setIcon(structureArray[x-1][z].getIcon());
            }
            terrainArray[0][z].setIcon(findEntry(map, new Coordinate(playerPos.getX() - 20, playerPos.getZ() - 11 + z)).returnTerrainIcon());
            structureArray[0][z].setIcon(findEntry(map, new Coordinate(playerPos.getX() - 20, playerPos.getZ() - 11 + z)).returnStructureIcon());
        }
    }
    
    public void moveRIGHT(JLabel[][] terrainArray, JLabel[][] structureArray, Coordinate[][] map, Coordinate playerPos) {
        for(int z = 0; z < 23; z++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < 40; x++) {
                terrainArray[x][z].setIcon(terrainArray[x+1][z].getIcon());
                structureArray[x][z].setIcon(structureArray[x+1][z].getIcon());
            }
            terrainArray[40][z].setIcon(findEntry(map, new Coordinate(playerPos.getX() + 20, playerPos.getZ() - 11 + z)).returnTerrainIcon());
            structureArray[40][z].setIcon(findEntry(map, new Coordinate(playerPos.getX() + 20, playerPos.getZ() - 11 + z)).returnStructureIcon());
        }
    }
    
    public static ImageIcon brightenImage(ImageIcon input, float brightness, float offset) {
        BufferedImage bI = new BufferedImage(input.getImage().getWidth(null),       input.getImage().getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D bIgr = bI.createGraphics();
        bIgr.drawImage(input.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
        bIgr.dispose();
        BufferedImage bO = new BufferedImage(input.getImage().getWidth(null), input.getImage().getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        
        RescaleOp rop = new RescaleOp(brightness, offset, null);
        
        bO = rop.filter(bI, null);
        ImageIcon output = new ImageIcon(bO);
        return output;
    }
    
//  public void update(JLabel[][] terrainArray, JLabel[][] structureArray, Coordinate[][] map, Coordinate playerPos) {
//      for(int i = 0; i < 41; i++) {
//          for(int j = 0; j < 23; j++) {
//              terrainArray[i][j].setIcon(findEntry(map, new Coordinate(playerPos.getX() - 20 + i, playerPos.getZ() - 11 + j)).returnTerrainIcon());
//              structureArray[i][j].setIcon(findEntry(map, new Coordinate(playerPos.getX() - 20 + i, playerPos.getZ() - 11 + j)).returnStructureIcon());
//          }
//      }
//  }
    
    public Coordinate findEntry(Coordinate[][] map, Coordinate pos) {
        Coordinate entry = null;
        for(int x = 0; x < Coordinate.MAP_SIZE; x++) {
            for(int z = 0; z < Coordinate.MAP_SIZE; z++) {
                if(pos.getX() == map[x][z].getX() && pos.getZ() == map[x][z].getZ()) {
                    entry = map[x][z];
                }
            }
        }
        return entry;
    }
    
}
```

**Coordinate Class**

```java
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Coordinate {
    
    private int x, z;
    private int alt;
    public static final int MAP_SIZE = 199;
    private ImageIcon str = Main.nullstructure;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getZ() {
        return z;
    }

    public void setZ(int z) {
        this.z = z;
    }

    public int getAlt() {
        return alt;
    }

    public void setAlt(int alt) {
        this.alt = alt;
    }

    public Coordinate(int x0, int z0) {
        this.x = x0;
        this.z = z0;
        
        int a = (int) Noise.mapTo(-1 * Math.sqrt(0.5), Math.sqrt(0.5), 0, 100, Noise.noise(x*0.1, z*0.1));
        int b = (int) Noise.mapTo(-1 * Math.sqrt(0.5), Math.sqrt(0.5), 0, 100, Noise.noise(x*0.05, z*0.05));
        int c = (int) Noise.mapTo(-1 * Math.sqrt(0.5), Math.sqrt(0.5), 0, 100, Noise.noise(x*0.01, z*0.01));
        this.alt = (int) ((0.55*c) + (0.25*b) + (0.20*a));
        if(Math.random() < 0.05 && alt >= 52 && alt < 70) {
            str = Main.oak;
        }
    }
    
    public ImageIcon returnTerrainIcon() {
        if(alt >= 0 && alt < 50) {
            return Main.water;
        }
        else if(alt >= 50 && alt < 52) {
            return Main.brightenImage(Main.sand, (float) ((float) 0.95 + ((alt - 50) * 0.025)), (float) 0.36);
        }
        else if(alt >= 52 && alt < 70) {
            return Main.brightenImage(Main.grass, (float) ((float) 0.85 + ((alt - 52) * 0.025)), (float) 0.36);
        }
        else if(alt >= 80 && alt < 90) {
            return Main.brightenImage(Main.stone, (float) ((float) 0.65 + ((alt - 70) * 0.05)), (float) 0.36);
        }
        else {
            return Main.ice;
        }
    }
    
    public ImageIcon returnStructureIcon() {
        return str;
    }
}
```

***Perlin (Not original)***

```java
import java.util.Random;

//<pre>
// Copyright 2001 Ken Perlin
// Courtesy of https://mrl.cs.nyu.edu/~perlin/experiments/packing/render/Noise.java
/** 
    Computes Perlin Noise for one, two, and three dimensions.<p>
    The result is a continuous function that interpolates a smooth path
    along a series random points. The function is consitent, so given
    the same parameters, it will always return the same value.
    @see ImprovedNoise
*/

public final class Noise {

   /** 
   Initialization seed used to start the random number generator.
   */
   static Random randseed = new Random();
   public static int seed = (int) Math.floor(randseed.nextInt());

   private static final int P = 8;
   private static final int B = 1 << P;
   private static final int M = B - 1;

   private static final int NP = 8;
   private static final int N = 1 << NP;

   private static int p[] = new int[B + B + 2];
   private static double g2[][] = new double[B + B + 2][2];
   private static double g1[] = new double[B + B + 2];
   private static double[][] points = new double[32][3];

   static {
      init();
   }

   private static double lerp(double t, double a, double b) {
      return a + t * (b - a);
   }

   private static double s_curve(double t) {
      return t * t * (3 - t - t);
   }

   /** 
   Computes noise function for one dimension at x.
   @param x 1 dimensional parameter
   @return the noise value at x 
   */
   public static double noise(double x) {

      int bx0, bx1;
      double rx0, rx1, sx, t, u, v;
      t = x + N;
      bx0 = ((int) t) & M;
      bx1 = (bx0 + 1) & M;
      rx0 = t - (int) t;
      rx1 = rx0 - 1;

      sx = s_curve(rx0);
      u = rx0 * g1[p[bx0]];
      v = rx1 * g1[p[bx1]];

      return lerp(sx, u, v);
   }

   /** 
   Computes noise function for two dimensions at the point (x,y).
   @param x x dimension parameter
   @param y y dimension parameter
   @return the value of noise at the point (x,y)
   */
   public static double noise(double x, double y) {

      int bx0, bx1, by0, by1, b00, b10, b01, b11;
      double rx0, rx1, ry0, ry1, sx, sy, a, b, t, u, v, q[];
      int i, j;

      t = x + N;
      bx0 = ((int) t) & M;
      bx1 = (bx0 + 1) & M;
      rx0 = t - (int) t;
      rx1 = rx0 - 1;

      t = y + N;
      by0 = ((int) t) & M;
      by1 = (by0 + 1) & M;
      ry0 = t - (int) t;
      ry1 = ry0 - 1;

      i = p[bx0];
      j = p[bx1];

      b00 = p[i + by0];
      b10 = p[j + by0];
      b01 = p[i + by1];
      b11 = p[j + by1];

      sx = s_curve(rx0);
      sy = s_curve(ry0);

      q = g2[b00];
      u = rx0 * q[0] + ry0 * q[1];
      q = g2[b10];
      v = rx1 * q[0] + ry0 * q[1];
      a = lerp(sx, u, v);

      q = g2[b01];
      u = rx0 * q[0] + ry1 * q[1];
      q = g2[b11];
      v = rx1 * q[0] + ry1 * q[1];
      b = lerp(sx, u, v);

      return lerp(sy, a, b);
   }

   /** 
   Computes noise function for three dimensions at the point (x,y,z).
   @param x x dimension parameter
   @param y y dimension parameter
   @param z z dimension parameter
   @return the noise value at the point (x, y, z)
   */
   static public double noise(double x, double y, double z) {

      int bx, by, bz, b0, b1, b00, b10, b01, b11;
      double rx0, rx1, ry0, ry1, rz, sx, sy, sz, a, b, c, d, u, v, q[];

      bx = (int) Math.IEEEremainder(Math.floor(x), B);
      if (bx < 0)
         bx += B;
      rx0 = x - Math.floor(x);
      rx1 = rx0 - 1;

      by = (int) Math.IEEEremainder(Math.floor(y), B);
      if (by < 0)
         by += B;
      ry0 = y - Math.floor(y);
      ry1 = ry0 - 1;

      bz = (int) Math.IEEEremainder(Math.floor(z), B);
      if (bz < 0)
         bz += B;
      rz = z - Math.floor(z);

      //if (bx < 0 || bx >= B + B + 2)
      //System.out.println(bx);

      b0 = p[bx];

      bx++;

      b1 = p[bx];

      b00 = p[b0 + by];
      b10 = p[b1 + by];

      by++;

      b01 = p[b0 + by];
      b11 = p[b1 + by];

      sx = s_curve(rx0);
      sy = s_curve(ry0);
      sz = s_curve(rz);

      q = G(b00 + bz);
      u = rx0 * q[0] + ry0 * q[1] + rz * q[2];
      q = G(b10 + bz);
      v = rx1 * q[0] + ry0 * q[1] + rz * q[2];
      a = lerp(sx, u, v);
      q = G(b01 + bz);
      u = rx0 * q[0] + ry1 * q[1] + rz * q[2];
      q = G(b11 + bz);
      v = rx1 * q[0] + ry1 * q[1] + rz * q[2];
      b = lerp(sx, u, v);
      c = lerp(sy, a, b);
      bz++;
      rz--;
      q = G(b00 + bz);
      u = rx0 * q[0] + ry0 * q[1] + rz * q[2];
      q = G(b10 + bz);
      v = rx1 * q[0] + ry0 * q[1] + rz * q[2];
      a = lerp(sx, u, v);
      q = G(b01 + bz);
      u = rx0 * q[0] + ry1 * q[1] + rz * q[2];
      q = G(b11 + bz);
      v = rx1 * q[0] + ry1 * q[1] + rz * q[2];
      b = lerp(sx, u, v);
      d = lerp(sy, a, b);

      return lerp(sz, c, d);
   }

   private static double[] G(int i) {
      return points[i % 32];
   }

   private static void init() {
      int i, j, k;
      double u, v, w, U, V, W, Hi, Lo;
      java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random(seed);
      for (i = 0; i < B; i++) {
         p[i] = i;
         g1[i] = 2 * r.nextDouble() - 1;

         do {
            u = 2 * r.nextDouble() - 1;
            v = 2 * r.nextDouble() - 1;
         } while (u * u + v * v > 1 || Math.abs(u) > 2.5 * Math.abs(v) || Math.abs(v) > 2.5 * Math.abs(u) || Math.abs(Math.abs(u) - Math.abs(v)) < .4);
         g2[i][0] = u;
         g2[i][1] = v;
         normalize2(g2[i]);

         do {
            u = 2 * r.nextDouble() - 1;
            v = 2 * r.nextDouble() - 1;
            w = 2 * r.nextDouble() - 1;
            U = Math.abs(u);
            V = Math.abs(v);
            W = Math.abs(w);
            Lo = Math.min(U, Math.min(V, W));
            Hi = Math.max(U, Math.max(V, W));
         } while (u * u + v * v + w * w > 1 || Hi > 4 * Lo || Math.min(Math.abs(U - V), Math.min(Math.abs(U - W), Math.abs(V - W))) < .2);
      }

      while (--i > 0) {
         k = p[i];
         j = (int) (r.nextLong() & M);
         p[i] = p[j];
         p[j] = k;
      }
      for (i = 0; i < B + 2; i++) {
         p[B + i] = p[i];
         g1[B + i] = g1[i];
         for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            g2[B + i][j] = g2[i][j];
         }
      }

      points[3][0] = points[3][1] = points[3][2] = Math.sqrt(1. / 3);
      double r2 = Math.sqrt(1. / 2);
      double s = Math.sqrt(2 + r2 + r2);

      for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
         for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            points[i][j] = (i == j ? 1 + r2 + r2 : r2) / s;
      for (i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
         for (j = 0; j <= 1; j++)
            for (k = 0; k <= 1; k++) {
               int n = i + j * 2 + k * 4;
               if (n > 0)
                  for (int m = 0; m < 4; m++) {
                     points[4 * n + m][0] = (i == 0 ? 1 : -1) * points[m][0];
                     points[4 * n + m][1] = (j == 0 ? 1 : -1) * points[m][1];
                     points[4 * n + m][2] = (k == 0 ? 1 : -1) * points[m][2];
                  }
            }
   }

   private static void normalize2(double v[]) {
      double s;
      s = Math.sqrt(v[0] * v[0] + v[1] * v[1]);
      v[0] = v[0] / s;
      v[1] = v[1] / s;
   }
   
   public static double mapTo(double a1, double a2, double b1, double b2, double x) {
      return b1 + ((x-a1)*(b2-b1))/(a2-a1);
   }
}
```

The icons and resources to be used are in this Github code (repository, I guess, I am new to Github):
https://github.com/rubiksRepository/Perlin.git

I would appreciate any help given. Thanks!

Comment: Another addendum: I am not using a Thread for the mapgen. However, I will use a Timer for circadian mechanics in the game. Maybe something to point out if these two time-related classes are something to be concerned about.

Comment: why dont you use a buffered image and draw your images onto the buffered image and display the image on the whole jframe?

Comment: Great idea, but would it affect the mechanics in a way? Since the game involves placing and breaking buildings and removing structures, I hypothesize that it would involve erasing a part of the image at that point, which might introduce lengthy code. Another concern is that it might involve (re)painting and drawing objects, which I want to avoid. Good idea though!

Comment: You would redraw the image whenever it changes or the window size changes. There is nothing wrong with redrawing it. You can also redraw only a portion of the image.
I assume the Grid Layout takes the most time to layout the ImageIcons and not the drawing itself. You should profile this first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, Raildex's suggestion is working. The compilation of the map into a single buffered image has reduced the lag tremendously and made the game "playable". For additions in the code, I have made a texture class that supports the textures used; and a MapField whose object has fields that have the compiled BufferImage.

```java
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class MapField {
    private BufferedImage terrain;
    private BufferedImage structure;
    
    public MapField(Coordinate[][] map) {
        BufferedImage[] colsT = new BufferedImage[Coordinate.MAP_SIZE];
        BufferedImage[] colsS = new BufferedImage[Coordinate.MAP_SIZE];
        for(int z = 0; z < Coordinate.MAP_SIZE; z++) {
            colsT[z] = Texture.mergeTeU(map[z]);
            colsS[z] = Texture.mergeStU(map[z]);
        }
        terrain = Texture.mergeH(colsT);
        structure = Texture.mergeH(colsS);
    }

    public BufferedImage getTerrain() {
        return terrain;
    }

    public void setTerrain(BufferedImage terrain) {
        this.terrain = terrain;
    }

    public BufferedImage getStructure() {
        return structure;
    }

    public void setStructure(BufferedImage structure) {
        this.structure = structure;
    }
}
```

Also in the Texture class, there are methods that can be used to merge rows and columns of BufferedImages, using a Graphics2D drawing process:

```java
public static BufferedImage toBI(ImageIcon input) {
        BufferedImage output = new BufferedImage(input.getImage().getWidth(null), input.getImage().getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D outputGr = output.createGraphics();
        outputGr.drawImage(input.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
        outputGr.dispose();
        return output;
    }
    
    public static BufferedImage mergeH(BufferedImage[] x) {
        int i = 0;
        BufferedImage rowOutput = new BufferedImage(x[0].getWidth() * x.length, x[0].getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D rowOutputG = rowOutput.createGraphics();
        for(BufferedImage xBI : x) {
            rowOutputG.drawImage(xBI, i * x[0].getWidth(), 0, null);
            i++;
        }
        rowOutputG.dispose();
        return rowOutput;
    }
    
    public static BufferedImage mergeTeH(Coordinate[] x) {
        BufferedImage[] xIcons = new BufferedImage[x.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            xIcons[i] = Texture.toBI(x[i].returnTerrainIcon());
        }
        return mergeH(xIcons);
    }
    
    public static BufferedImage mergeStH(Coordinate[] x) {
        BufferedImage[] xIcons = new BufferedImage[x.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            xIcons[i] = Texture.toBI(x[i].returnStructureIcon());
        }
        return mergeH(xIcons);
    }
    
    public static BufferedImage mergeU(BufferedImage[] x) {
        int i = 0;
        BufferedImage colOutput = new BufferedImage(x[0].getWidth(), x[0].getHeight() * x.length, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D colOutputG = colOutput.createGraphics();
        for(BufferedImage xBI : x) {
            colOutputG.drawImage(xBI, 0, i * x[0].getHeight(), null);
            i++;
        }
        colOutputG.dispose();
        return colOutput;
    }
    
    public static BufferedImage mergeTeU(Coordinate[] x) {
        BufferedImage[] xIcons = new BufferedImage[x.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            xIcons[i] = Texture.toBI(x[i].returnTerrainIcon());
        }
        return mergeU(xIcons);
    }
    
    public static BufferedImage mergeStU(Coordinate[] x) {
        BufferedImage[] xIcons = new BufferedImage[x.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            xIcons[i] = Texture.toBI(x[i].returnStructureIcon());
        }
        return mergeU(xIcons);
    }
```

So the bottomline is: for scroll-based maps, you can compile the textures corresponding to the map to improve playability (FPS or lag reduction). For interaction with the game, editing the BufferedImage at a pixel range via turning it to transparency or changing textures can help, at least for me. Not really great in answering the general gist since I am addressing my case only (trying to emulate this solution on others though) and the scroll-base map is on a case-to-case basis, but I hope my solution helps.